# Как может md5 корректно работать?

Tags: хеширование, md5

Если взять любую строку и md5-ировать 36^32 раз (кол-во вариантов md5-строк), то после этого результаты начнут повторяться. И получится, что например md5 от "hello" совпадает с md5 другого слова.
В чем я не прав?

Comment: А зачем вообще делать так: `md5(md5(...))`? Что вы пытаетесь этим сделать? Или вы думаете, что это надежнее? Советую почитать про [Коллизия хеш-функции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Comment: А почему Вы считаете, что это некорректное поведение?

Comment: @And Я ничего не пытаюсь сделать, просто я так доказал, что md5 никакой строки не уникален

Comment: @Yaant Ну я просто не думал что в md5 есть такой очевидный недостаток

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MD5, как и все другие хеши, предназначен для того, что бы быстро оценить, что строка с большой вероятностью та же самая. При этом хранить небольшой объем информации (16 байт). Единственным доказательством точного равенства строк может служить только сравнение исходных строк или их образов после однозначного кодирования, такого как сжатие архивирующими алгоритмами. Но бесконечно сжать строку, без потери информации не возможно.

Когда вам требуется оценить, с приемлемой точностью, что перед вами тот же самый файл, размером 1 гигабайт, не храня сам файл, хеши единственный выход. Если вы считаете, что для вашей задачи вероятность коллизии в MD5 слишком высока, воспользуйтесь другим хешем или сразу несколькими. Но разумеется вы лишь уменьшите вероятность ошибки.

А применять md5 несколько раз к результату другого md5 не имеет никакого смысла. Если md5 двух строк изначально равны, то и выполненные много раз так же будут равны. При этом обратное (заключение равенства объектов по равенству много раз повторенного md5) с очень большой вероятностью работает, но уже не гарантировано, потому что могут найтись две 16 байтные последовательности, которые дадут одинаковый md5.

Comment: Так получается не имеет смысла и разные хеши использовать. Если md5 двух строк совпадает, то md5(sha1()) этих строк тоже совпадает.

Comment: @Miqayel Разумеется. Но вот если есть две _разные_ строки (`X != Y`),  у которых `md5(X)=md5(Y)`, то вероятность что и `sha1(X)=sha1(Y)` крайне мала, потому что алгоритм совершенно другой. Тогда получаем что если мы храним md5 от исходной строки и sha1 от этой же исходной строки (а не от md5), то общая вероятность коллизии выходит около `1 / 2^288`

Comment: Круто!) А я не подумал) Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

По задумке результат хеш-функции должен не отличаться случайного числа. А значит цикл может начаться через любое количество итераций `n`, где `1 <= n <= 2^128`. Вполне возможно существует такая строка `x`, что `md5(x) = x`.

То, что хеш-функция "зацикливается", в этом нет ничего плохого, это ожидаемое поведение с точки зрения теории вероятностей.